# Unable to add data to an array taken out from a cookie

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

Am not able to add data to an array taken out from a cookie .

```
var x1 =[];
 if($cookies.get(uid )== undefined)
              {
                var arr =[];
                arr.push($scope.stock);
                $cookies.put("arr",JSON.stringify(arr));
                $cookies.put("uid","xxx");
                console.log("==uid not found in cookie in angular --- cookies.uid"+ $cookies.get("arr"));
              }
          else
              {
                 console.log("inside else"+JSON.stringify($cookies.getObject("arr"))); // gives output ["bse:yesbank"]
                 x1= JSON.stringify($cookies.getObject("arr"));
              ---->  console.log(x1 instanceof Array); // returns false 
              ---->   x1.push($scope.stock);

              }
```

it gives 
x1.push is not a function

Moreover, it's says the `JSON.stringify($cookies.getObject("arr"))` is not an array but the value of above expression is `["bse:yesbank"]` which is nothing but an array. please correct me where I am getting wrong .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you use `JSON.stringify`, wich turns the array into a string looking like the array.

Try to get the value without stringify:

```js
x1= JSON.stringify(["test"]);
console.log(x1 instanceof Array); // returns false 

console.log(JSON.parse(x1) instanceof Array); // returns true
```